# Binding issue in select using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am facing an issue while developing my SharePoint app which is generating charts using fetched data from server.

I have a configuration page which loads/saves configuration. Now my problem is i am storing selected value of dropdown to SP list and again fetching the same record to bind on select.

For e.g. i have stored 'column1' in list and getting & assigning in scope variable. Now scope variable value is not appearing in dropdown.

I have created a dummy fiddle for my problem.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ritesh14887/HB7LU/18102/)

Here, i have `$scope.selectedModel = 'Column1';` preselected but it is not selected by default.

Comment: can you post your json object ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're setting the dropdown list anywhere?

Comment: @underscore : I have updated latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ritesh14887/HB7LU/18102/

Comment: @EstebanFelix : I just want the selectedModel value to be default value in dropdown...

Comment: just use `$scope.selectedModel = "LinkTitle";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.selectedModel = $scope.fields1[0];
```

could do the trick. "Column1" is not a reference to the selected object.

Updated the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18103/)

**Edit**: Actually I like  Sherali Turdiyev's answer more, since I removed the 'obj.internalName as' from your code, which I also forgot to mention.

Comment: I dont want to select first value from JSON object, i want to select value which i am getting from server list. for e.g. $scope.selectedModel = 'zfcu';

Comment: Use `$scope.selectedModel = "LinkTitle";`, as Sherali Turdiyev said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your selected value in a variable with name *yourSelectedItem* and the same sturcture than the objects you have on your *fields1* array, you just need to do:

```
$scope.selectedModel = yourSelectedItem.internalName;
```

You are using internalName property as key of select list

**jsfiddle** updated http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18104/